# Is it possible to dynamically create the name of a table in a stored procedure with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, sql-delete

Take a look at this code. It should show you what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT type from barcodes where barcode = barcodeApp INTO @barcodeType;
IF (@barcodeType = 'videogame') THEN 
    SET @barcodeType = 'game';
END IF;

DELETE FROM @barcodeType + itemdetails_custom
WHERE barcode = barcodeApp
AND username = usernameApp;
```

As you can see, on the `DELETE FROM` part, I would like to dynamically put together the table name from a result of a previous query. Is this possible?

Also, if you see issues with the above queries, please let me know. I'm by no means a MySQL expert obviously.

Comment: What are `barcodeApp` and `usernameApp` ? Variables or column names?

Comment: Yes, variables sent in from the user into the sproc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Prepared Statement` to execute dynamically prepared queries.

Try following code:

```
set @del_query = concat( 'DELETE FROM ', @finalType )
set @del_query = concat( '\'', itemdetails_custom, '\'' );
set @del_query = concat( @del_query, ' WHERE barcode = \'', barcodeApp, '\'' );
set @del_query = concat( @del_query, ' AND username = \'', usernameApp, '\'' );

prepare stmt from @del_query;
execute stmt;
drop prepare stmt; -- deallocate prepare stmt;
```

*Note*: I assumed that `barcodeApp` and `usernameApp` are variables. Otherwise remove single quotes around them in the query above.

Comment: Works! You forgot the single quotes around itemdetails_custom though. :)